# how to set busy indicator when switching pages?

Tags: sapui5, busyindicator

I have an SAPUI5 application with 2 pages. When I click on a button it grabs data from the backend and then it proceeds to the next page to display the data. This can take some time based on the amount of data so I want to add a busy indicator between the pages so it doesn't look like the first page is frozen. The problem is that the busy indicator doesn't show up until the second page has loaded which is not what I want.

This is a code sample of my first page controller where I call the busy indicator

```
onButtonPress: function(){
  //code to grab input data
  var errorsFound = this.checkData();
  if(errorsFound)
       //code to show errors here
  else{
    var BI = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
    BI.open();
    this.processData(); //call function to make ajax call to backend and get data
    this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("page2");
    }
 },

checkData: function(){
  //check data for errors;

return errorsFound;  

}
```

on my second page I have this

```
onInit: function(){
  var route = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  route.getRoute("page2").attachMatched(this.initController, this);

}

initController: function(){
 //here I have code to grab the data that came back and I set model to display it

 //Dialog doesn't show up until the app hits comes around this point.

}
```

Not sure how to make this work, the busy indicator won't come up until the next page comes up. I even tried using the xml fragment like in this example and got the same result.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.BusyDialogLight/preview

Any pointers on how to do this right would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it the wrong way around. First, navigate the second page and then load the data. This will simplify your app and the whole thing will feel much more natural.

I see you're using the router, if you're depending on a specific variable, you might want to change it to include a route parameter. If you set them in your manifest, it would looks something like:

*manifest.json*

```
"routes": [{
    "pattern": "/page2/{parameter}",
    "name": "page2",
    "target": "page2"
}]
```

And in your controller navigate like this:

*page1.controller.js*

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("page2", {
   parameter: "my-unique-id" 
});
```

You'll find the parameter ready for you to use in data binding or anything else in the event on the pattern matched (note the change in function here)

*page2.controller.js*

```
route.getRoute("page2").attachPatternMatched(this.initController, this);
```

In which case the callback has your parameter:

*page2.controller.js*

```
initController: function(oEvent) {
    var myParameter = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").parameter

    // set the busy indicators and load your data here
}
```

The added bonus of this approach is that you can navigate directly to `myapp#/page2/my-unique-id` and it will just load everything without relying on the button on page1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind **busy** property to your App control, and set it default as false and set true or false dynamically as per your requirement. Try to keep as simple (Should not use for specific page.)

Comment: I tried doing that but couldn't make it work. I think the problem seems to be with the ajax call. I have it being synchronous instead of async. This causes the the waiting indicator to take longer to show up. Not sure why. But if I set the ajax call to async, the indicator shows up at the right time, with the problem that now I having issues with getting the data on the page on time. It tries to render the page before the data comes back